# How to query sender address from copay?

Tags: copay, bitpay

I have **transaction ID** and some other data in my disposal when I am on first screen on Copay wallet. I need to show in transaction details originating address for transfer to my wallet.

Is there some API endpoint I can hit in bitpay API ?

Answer (score 1):

copay didn't provide this information for the transaction. It can be retrieved from other APIs.